# Does Jackson serialize getter property for an undefined field?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-restcontroller

I have a class with the following fields and their respective getters, plus an additional method `getTotalBalance` for which I don't have any field but a custom implementation.

```
    public class demo{
    private String balance;
    private String blockedBalace;
    private String futureBalance;
    private String availableBalance;
    //getters for previous fields
    public String getTotalBalance(){
    //something..
    }
```

When I serialize an object of this class I get the following JSON output.

```
     {
      "balance": "12.30",
      "blockedBalance":"23.45",
      "futureBalance" :"56.22",
      "availableBalance" :"12.30",
      "totalBalance" : "34.11"
     }
```

Even if I didn't declare a field for `totalBalance`, I've got this serialized in the end. How is it possible?

Comment: Note that Java behavior is generally defined around _properties_, which are defined by the (public) getters and/or setters; whether those properties have backing fields is usually formally irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This behavior makes much more sense now.

Comment: Just to clarify where the text `"totalBalance"` is coming from, in the JSON: I assume (but I don't have an official reference/citation) that Jackson is following the [JavaBeans naming standards](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javaserver-pages-3rd/0596005636/ch20s01s01.html) (replace the `get`, and then make the `T` lowercase) to convert the method name into a JSON key. (The reverse of what getter code generators typically do.) Someone correct me if wrong?

Comment: @andrewJames that's pretty much it, but also it will convert consecutive initial uppercase letters to lowercase (example `getID` becomes "id")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jackson by default uses the getters for serializing and setters for deserializing.

You can use `@JsonIgnore` over your getter method to ignore it, OR you can configure your object mapper to use the fields only for serialization/des:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
```

Answer (score 1):

Jackson doesn't (by default) care about fields. It will simply serialize everything provided by getters and deserialize everything with a matching setter. What those getters/setters do is of no consequence.

Mind you though, that every little thing about Jackson can be deeply customized and configured, so I'm only talking about the default setup.

Comment: This was weird for me at first  to achieve serialization/deserialization of objects with this default setup. Now that I learned it , I can try to configure it . Thank you